# How can i read text from socket Kotlin/Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, socket.io

I will say right away that I started to study Kotlin recently, and I just want to rewrite one program, and therefore I took up this

I want to read the text received from the incoming stream, but as a result, I get the following

Perhaps I make terribly stupid mistakes, but I hardly understand what and how it works here
(I read half Internet)

[I don't know what is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzXZX.png)

P.S.
[I already tried to use this, but the program just doesn't go further and that's it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgJQc.png)

````kotlin
package com.example.appisone
import java.net.Socket
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var Text_Edit: EditText? = null
    private var btn: Button? = null
    private var Text_view: TextView? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        Text_Edit = findViewById(R.id.EditText)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.Button)
        Text_view = findViewById(R.id.TextView)
        btn?.setOnClickListener {
            Text_view?.text = Text_Edit?.text
            println("Button is pressed!")
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                send_text()

            }
        }


    }

    private fun send_text() {
        var data: Any
        println("send_text is pressed!")
        val client = Socket("192.168.0.3", 9090)
        val text = Text_Edit?.text.toString()
        println(text.toByteArray())
        client.getOutputStream().write(text.toByteArray())

        val reader = client.getInputStream()



        data = reader.toString()
        println("Сообщение --- >$data")



    }


}  ```


Thanks in advance for your wasted time
````

Comment: *"Thanks in advance for your wasted time"* - [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  It wastes our time to continually need to remind people of this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't read from a `Reader` like this:

```
reader.toString()
```

That just renders the `Reader` >>object<< as a string.  Since `toString` has not been overridden by `Reader`, you get the `Object::toString` implementation.  (It prints the internal class name and the object's "identity hash code" in hexadecimal.)

To read from a `Reader` use one of the `read` methods in the [Reader API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html), or wrap it in a `Scanner` or a `BufferedReader` so that you can use those APIs.

---

In your "P.S." you are also calling toString() on an object that doesn't override toString(). Based on the class name, it looks like it is a byte[].

Comment: I used this `data = reader.read(x)` method, but now all I get is 0. I read the documentation but couldn't really figure it out